# Search a list by keyword

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to search for the existence of a keyword within a list of strings. Here is what the list would look like:

```
Milk, 2
Eggs, 4
Juice,1
```

I just want to search the list by giving a grocery list item. I only want it to search the first word in each index of the list for the grocery item name and ignore the count next to the item name. How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the items into `Dictionary<string, int>` and then just lookup by key.

```
List<string> items = new List<string> {
    "Milk, 2",
    "Eggs, 4",
    "Juice, 1"
};
var dictionary = items.Select(s => s.Split(',')) 
                      .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => Int32.Parse(x[1]));

bool contains = dictionary.ContainsKey("Milk");
```

Comment: is that the most efficient/fastest/shortest method possible?

Comment: @Greg: I don't know, it depends on your usage. But your stated goal is to efficiently search a list for a given item. A dictionary will give you `O(1)` lookup. Keeping it in a list will give you `O(n)` lookup (or `O(log n)` if you keep it sorted and do a binary search). Knowing nothing else, a dictionary is probably best because it gives you extremely fast look up.

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredList = groceryList.Where(i => i.Contains(searchString)).ToList()
```

should work.

Alternatively you can do `i.StartsWith(inputString)` or `inputString.Equals(i.Split(",")[0])`.

Comment: is that the most efficient/fastest/shortest method possible?

Answer (score 0):

I like Bala's direction and it works if you want the entire line(s) the search string is found in. If you need to only get the item, you will have to Split the string.

Answer (score 0):

Following returns null if not found...

```
string searchTerm = "Milk";
string item = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.StartsWith(searchTerm + ","));
```